# How can i end this code without the new line at the end?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am going through the HackerRank challenges at the moment, and in this particular exercise I need to print multiple lines, except that a the end the code is printing out a new, blank one which I don't want since it is causing the website to consider the whole output wrong. Is there a way I can make it so only the last line I want printed won't print a new one?
Here is the code I'm talking about:

```
h, w = input().split(' ')
h = int(h)
w= int(w)
def main(w, h):
    p = '.|.'
    c = 0
    for i in range(int(float(h)/2)):
        print((p*(i*2+1)).center(w, '-'))
        c = i*2+1
    print('Welcome'.center(w, '-'))
    for i in range(int(float(h)/2)):
        print(((p*(c-i*2)).center(w, '-')))
main(w, h)
```

And the [link](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/designer-door-mat/problem) to the challenge.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just modify the last loop.

In fact, you can tell python to do not write the carriage return in print

```
h, w = input().split(' ')
h = int(h)
w= int(w)
def main(w, h):
    p = '.|.'
    c = 0
    for i in range(int(float(h)/2)):
        print((p*(i*2+1)).center(w, '-'))
        c = i*2+1
    print('Welcome'.center(w, '-'))
    for i in range(int(float(h)/2) - 1):
        print(((p*(c-i*2)).center(w, '-')))
    print(((p*(c-i*2)).center(w, '-')), end='')
main(w, h)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can construct the string and print it all at once instead of printing each line separately (this way you can remove the last new line character):

```
def main(w, h):
    p = '.|.'
    c = 0
    s = ''
    for i in range(h // 2):   #   a // b is the same as int(a / b)
        s += (p*(i*2+1)).center(w, '-') + '\n'
    c = (h // 2 - 1) * 2 + 1   #   only this value is used
    s += 'Welcome'.center(w, '-') + '\n'
    for i in range(h // 2):
        s += ((p*(c-i*2)).center(w, '-')) + '\n'
    s = s[:-1]
    print(s, end='')
```